# Why does this require an if statement to execute

Tags: enums, swift, swift-playground

In the swift book by Apple, there is an enum example. It lets you convert a raw Int to a enum rank. However when I try to remove the if statement, the code gives me

> Playground execution failed: error: :30:13: error: 'Rank?' does not have a member named 'simpleDesciption'

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King

    func simpleDesciption() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .Ace:
                return "ace"
            case .Jack:
                return "jack"
            case .Queen:
                return "queen"
            case .King:
                return "king"
            default:
                return String(self.toRaw())
        }
    }
}

if let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(1){
    let threeDescription = convertedRank.simpleDesciption()
}

// Why does it need to be wrapped in a if statement?

let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(1)
let threeDescription = convertedRank.simpleDesciption()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if let` construct allows to unwrap an optional type. The `Rank.fromRaw` returns the `Rank?` optional type, which means it could either be `nil` or an actual value of the type.

There are two ways to unwrap the value of an optional type in Swift, one of which is the `if let` construct. The body of the `if let` is executed if the optional type is not `nil`, and the variable that follows `if let` is bound to its value (and thus has type `Rank`, not `Rank?`).

Note that if you simply write `let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(1)` without the `if`, `convertedRank` has the type `Rank?` and, again, cannot be directly used as a `Rank` without being unwrapped.

If you are ***sure*** that the value will never be `nil`, you can force-unwrap it by suffixing the variable name with `!`:

```
let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(1)
convertedRank!.simpleDescription()
```

But this is not recommended style, as it will fail at runtime if the value is not defined.

Comment: Is this optional type to prevent errors, by checking if convertedRank actually has a value?